# ePub and Apple Books Grey and Black mode background-color doesn't work

Tags: css, ios, ibooks, macos-ventura, epub3

This affects Apple Books ePub rendering. I am able to render the ePub in dark mode in other readers using either prefers-color-scheme or a fallback dark class (or, in the case of Calibre, setting `body.calibre-viewer-dark-colors {}` where needed.

For the most part, `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` is working for Apple Books.
However, I appear to be unable to set `background-color` and have it work in Grey and Night. Sepia shows just fine.

The two items I need a background-color on are `pre` and forcing a white background onto svg images.

I've used:

```
pre {
    background-color: #212427;
}

img[src ^= "data:image/svg"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;

  }
```

within the `media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` but it doesn't seem to matter for Apple Books specifically (other readers relying on this are working). I've also tried setting `!important` but no dice. The backgrounds work fine in light mode and Sepia.